# python google street view

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-street-view

I installed google_streetview via pip on my computer through Anaconda. Then I imported the module in a jupyter notebook as:

```
import google_streetview
```

this works successfully, but I am not able to proceed any further such as set my developer key or even access help with the -h command.

```
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

Note, when I follow this on my computer's python terminal these commands seem to work, but not in jupyter or spyder.

I am likely making a fundamental error in how to access packages, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give us the code that raised the error?

Comment: Sure, it is basically all commands that reference the module, for example `google_streetview -h` or `google_streetview -s key`, or even directly using it such as `google_streetview --location="46.414382,10.013988"` These all work in the anaconda terminal but not elsewhere.

Comment: What is "else where" ? Those are command lines, not lines of code. Can I see the python file that you try to write? You can edit your post and write the code and errors you encountered.

Comment: By 'elsewhere' I mean on jupyter notebook or in spyder notebook. I guess then my issue is that I can not get the command lines to work, without that I can't write any code. Is there something very simple i'm missing about command lines functionality? because something like `dir(google_streetview)` works